# select only certain fields in an mvc linq query that has multiple includes

Tags: c#, entity-framework

When looking at generated json,I saw that a rules page was including image data.  I traced it to this code:  `

```
.Include(m => m.OrderRuleType)
            .Include(m => m.OrderRuleType.Type)
            .Include(m => m.OrderRuleType.Category)
            // best match fields
            .Include(m => m.TicketType)
            .Include(m => m.DestTicketType)
            .Include(m => m.Shipper)
            .Include(m => m.CarrierType)
            .Include(m => m.Carrier)
            .Include(m => m.DriverGroup)
            .Include(m => m.Driver)
            .Include(m => m.TruckType)
            .Include(m => m.ProductGroup)
            .Include(m => m.Destination)
            .Include(m => m.Origin)
            .Include(m => m.DestState)
            .Include(m => m.OriginState)
            .Include(m => m.DestRegion)
            .Include(m => m.OriginRegion)
            .Include(m => m.Producer)
        .Where(m => !m.OrderRuleType.Hidden)
        .Where(m => m.ID == id || id == 0)
```

I tried doing a .select on the offending include (shipper) like this:

```
.Select(m => new { m.ID, m.Name}})
```

that caused a red line for all code after it.
I tried putting an .asEnumerable() on it as well.

What is the proper way to select just multiple fields from these?  Pretty much all of them we are only using the ID and name field from that table.

I could probably do a .select at the very end, but i do not know if it's possible to select out values like that without creating a view model.  I tried adding a select after the shipper include but it broke all following includes.

Comment: The red line is Intellisense indicating an error.  Can you share it with us? Otherwise we really won't know how to help here since we can't see definitions for any of these classes

Comment: they all contain at the very least "ID" and "Name" and that's all i need.  The grid shows the name in each column.  The problem is that, specifically the shippers model, it has an image stored in each record.  when i tried to do a select on the offending include, the next include thought i was trying to include it in the anonymous type i was creating.  The only way i know of to make this work is create a view model but i would rather just select out the data i want.

Comment: what are you trying to return?  A list of unhidden rules?  If that's the case what's with all the .Include() statements.  This query seems like it's going to be extremely poor performing because of the sheer number of includes.  include is going to bring in the whole entity.  I'd get rid of all the .Include() statements and craft a .Select projection with only the information you need.  That will tailor you select to only the fields you care about and not every property of every included entity.

Comment: how would i select from a model i haven't included?  I don't know how to do that.
the base model has id fields and foreign-key mapped included models, mostly for the sole purpose of just looking up their names.  I just recently created a carrier rules page similar to this one but mine doesn't have the performance issues this one has as i am pulling my data from a database view.  I am marginal at linq so i don't know how to fix this.

Comment: When you specify a property in the Select projection like m.OrderRuleType.Category.Name, it will pull in the correct information using your entity mappings.

Comment: I was able to solve it, but you definitely helped.  Upvoting your comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by using an anonymous select.  I was not able to select directly into the model for two reasons:  1.  Some of the fields (all the named ones) were notmapped fields without setters, and 2.  The model was bound to a table.  Here is working code:

```
var data = db.OrderRules
                        .Include(m => m.OrderRuleType)
                        .Include(m => m.OrderRuleType.Type)
                        .Include(m => m.OrderRuleType.Category)
                        // best match fields
                        .Include(m => m.TicketType)
                        .Include(m => m.DestTicketType)
                        .Include(m => m.Shipper)
                        .Include(m => m.CarrierType)
                        .Include(m => m.Carrier)
                        .Include(m => m.DriverGroup)
                        .Include(m => m.Driver)
                        .Include(m => m.TruckType)
                        .Include(m => m.ProductGroup)
                        .Include(m => m.Destination)
                        .Include(m => m.Origin)
                        .Include(m => m.DestState)
                        .Include(m => m.OriginState)
                        .Include(m => m.DestRegion)
                        .Include(m => m.OriginRegion)
                        .Include(m => m.Producer)
                    .Where(m => !m.OrderRuleType.Hidden)
                    .Where(m => m.ID == id || id == 0)
                    .Select(m => new { 
                        m.ID,
                        allowRowDeactivate = true,
                        allowRowEdit = true,
                        m.EffectiveDate,
                        m.EndDate,
                        m.Value,
                        m.TypeID,
                        m.OrderRuleType,
                        m.OrderRuleType.Type,
                        m.OrderRuleType.Category,
                        OriginTicketTypeName = m.TicketType.Name ?? BestMatchCore.DEFAULT_LABEL,
                        DestTicketTypeName = m.DestTicketType.Name ?? BestMatchCore.DEFAULT_LABEL,
                        ShipperName = m.Shipper.Name ?? BestMatchCore.DEFAULT_LABEL,
                        CarrierTypeName = m.CarrierType.Name ?? BestMatchCore.DEFAULT_LABEL,
                        CarrierName = m.Carrier.Name ?? BestMatchCore.DEFAULT_LABEL,
                        DriverGroupName = m.DriverGroup.Name ?? BestMatchCore.DEFAULT_LABEL,
                        DriverName = (m.Driver.FirstName + " " + m.Driver.LastName == " ")? BestMatchCore.DEFAULT_LABEL: m.Driver.FirstName + " " + m.Driver.LastName,
                        TruckTypeName = m.TruckType.Name ?? BestMatchCore.DEFAULT_LABEL,
                        ProductGroupName = m.ProductGroup.Name ?? BestMatchCore.DEFAULT_LABEL,
                        DestinationName = m.Destination.Name ?? BestMatchCore.DEFAULT_LABEL,
                        OriginName = m.Origin.Name ?? BestMatchCore.DEFAULT_LABEL,
                        DestStateName = m.DestState.Abbreviation ?? BestMatchCore.DEFAULT_LABEL,
                        OriginStateName = m.OriginState.Abbreviation ?? BestMatchCore.DEFAULT_LABEL,
                        DestRegionName = m.DestRegion.Name ?? BestMatchCore.DEFAULT_LABEL,
                        OriginRegionName = m.OriginRegion.Name ?? BestMatchCore.DEFAULT_LABEL,
                        ProducerName = m.Producer.Name ?? BestMatchCore.DEFAULT_LABEL,
                        CreateDate = m.CreateDateUTC,
                        m.CreatedByUser,
                        LastChangeDate = m.LastChangeDateUTC,
                        m.LastChangedByUser

                        });
```

This created a query that only brought back the fields i wanted.